# how to import zxing source for android into eclipse?

Tags: zxing

I have checked out the source of zxing from Subversion, and I would like to import the source to Eclipse IDE so I can examine the code and then make my project, which uses zxing.

How can I import the source?

If I choose File->Import->Existing Project into workspace, Eclipse doesn't seem to find the project!

Also, do I have to import the project to the workspace or simply add some libraries to my project in order to use it?

Comment: isn't it better to just install the app [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) rather then copy some parts? When done that you could call it via an `Intent` like this: Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); startActivity(intent);

Comment: Once again I should mention that the ZXing creator Sean Owen mentioned that integrating the barcode scanner as a whole is not a good solution unless absolutely necessary.
So Intent calling of the Barcode Scanne would be the preferred way of doing things.

Comment: While I appreciate the support, this is not really what I have said. Copying the UI completely is not OK. Copying our manifest declarations and namespace is not OK. But using the source code is fine (if you comply with the open source license).

Comment: While I agree with this sentiment entirely, I think it's fair to ask just how to import and view the source. Nothing wrong there per se.

Comment: There is nothing special about the project in this regard. Just attach the source in `core/src` as a source root in your project. You can build and attach `core.jar` to your project to access it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial [Click here](http://android-peoplesconnect.blogspot.com/2013/03/integrating-zxing-in-your-android.html) but instead of dowloading the 2.1 version, I downloaded the 2.2 and dowload the core.jar from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/2.2). If you dont know how to import the library check [this](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/development-tools/eclipse-android-tutorial-working-with-libraries.html).